# ObservableCollection(T).CollectionChanged Event

Tags: c#

```
SelectedObjects.CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.NewItems.Count);//prints out 1 if a new item is added
};
```

one thing i am not sure of is why e.OldItems and e.NewItems are collections?

if i add multiple items per second the event gets fired foreach item and the output is always 1 meaning that it gets fired multiple times, but is there a way to delay the event firing, for example after 5 seconds of the change so that i could get every change in those 5 seconds in the e.OldItems or the e.NewItems?

Comment: One important thing to note is that `CollectionChanged` and its event args is not specific to any of the pre-defined types such as `ObservableCollection<T>`. It is defined by [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which in turn is the interface that bindings look for. So, if *you* need or want a collection that updates only sporadically and aggregates several subsequent changes, you can write it yourself and the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface provides full support for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  The point of an observable collection is to raise the event when it is modified.  Whilst in your use-case it is desirable to be notified after a set amount of time, it is not *every* use-case and would over-complicate the class.

What you could do is wrap the observable collection in to a custom class that you create (e.g. `DelayedObservableCollection<T>`, and that - in conjunction with a timer -, raises its' own event when items are added/modified, and then no items are added/modified after a specified time, or more than 'x' items are added/modified.